# How to find the minimum distance from a point to a set?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $M=\{x: x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}+x_{3}^{2}\le4, x_{1}^{2}-4x_{2}\le0\}$ and $y=(1,0,2)^{T}$. Find the minimum distance from $y$ to $M$, the unique minimizing point and a separating plane. Does anyone know how to solve the problem without KKT conditions? It would be very helpful.

Comment: Probably you mean from $y$ to $M$. In general you want to  calculate the length of a vector from $y$ to $p(y)$, where $p(y)$ is the projection of $y$ onto $M$. Haven't done any calculations myself, I write this on a mobile on a bus..

Comment: can you add reference to the type of projection theorem you are referring to ?

Comment: Let $M$ be a nonempty closed convex set and $y\notin M$. Then there exist a unique point $x \in M$  with minimum distance from $y$. Furthermore, $x$ is the minimazing point if and only if $(y-x)^{T}(z-x)\le 0$ for all $z\in M$.

Comment: The "projection theorem" is purely an existence theorem. It only tells you such a point exist, but doesn't provide an apparatus for producing such. So it's awkward to want to find a projection point unto an arbitrary set using the "projection theorem".

Comment: You are right, so is there any way how to find the point without solving KKT conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Finding the minimum distance from $y$ to $M$ can be done by solving the following problem: Minimize
$$
d=(x_1-1)^2+{x_2}^2+(x_3-2)^2\quad\quad \quad \mbox{(the squared distance to $y$)}
$$
subject to:
\begin{align}
{x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+{x_3}^2&\le 4\\
{x_1}^2-4{x_2}&\le 0
\end{align}

You can solve this with KKT conditions if you are familiar with non linear optimization. Actually this also gives you the unique minimizing point (its coordinates are the triplet $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ of the solution).

Comment: I know, but this is complicated and long solution, I am supposed to use a shorter one using projection theorem.

Comment: @Laura: You should note that in your question.

Comment: @Laura it is not long at all. note you can eliminate $x_2$,then you will find you can eliminate another one, so it is a single $f(x)$ min problem.

Comment: I am note sure you can eliminate $x_2$ given that a priori, we do not know if the constraints will be satisfied to equality.

Comment: @Kuifje: From the third constraint, it is clear that $x_2 \ge 0$. If you lower the value of $x_2$, then the objective will become smaller and the first constraint will remain satisfied. Hence, the third constraint has to be satisfied with equality.